# How can we spawn 1 selected prefab and 3 random prefabs from a list of prefabs randomly at 4 fixed positions?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Quiz-type game where there will be a question and 1 answer to the question. The question will be displayed on the top and options will drop down, from which the answer needs to be caught in a basket. The scene has 4 vertical columns where the options drop from. I want it to be random (every time the scene loads, the options should drop randomly from the 4 positions, shouldn't drop from the same column every time). How do I randomize this? Please help me with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question should have had a segment of the code you used for your random spawning. But I can assume that you're using `UnityEngine.Random.Range(_, _)` for your random number.

Give that, you can use something like this to seed your RNG:

```
UnityEngine.Random.InitState ( DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond );
```

The chances that you'll get the same Millisecond value is so small ( 0 - 999), you can consider it random, in instances such as this, with 4 possible values. `DateTime.Ticks` might seem more appropriate, except that Ticks is a `long` value, and `Random.InitState(int)` requires an `int` argument.

Comment: I think It will appear as a pattern? isn't it?

Comment: The purpose of 'seeding' a RNG (Random Number Generator) is so that you don't get the same pattern occurring, or, given the same seed, making sure that the same 'random' pattern DOES occur every time.

Comment: Okay, let me try that. Thanks for the help ✌